# Determine whether the following statements are true or false, and then prove answers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Determine whether statement is true or false, and then prove answer.
For all integers $a,b,c$:
a) if $a|bc$ and gcd$(a,b) = 1$ then $a|c$
b) if $a|c$ and $a|b$ and gcd$(a,b) = 1$ then $ab|c$.

I've answered versions of these questions without the "and gcd$(a,b) = 1$", but I'm not sure if and how that affects whether the statement is true or false.

Comment: Well what does it mean for their gcd to be 1?

Comment: Consider if $a=1$ for the second part that likely doesn't hold.

Comment: @JBKing: Indeed, if $a|b$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $a$ has to be $1$.

Comment: @TonyK, $a$ could be -1 for another possibility here.

Answer (score 1):

Bezout's identity. If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime then there exist integers $x,y$  such that $ax+by=1$

Multiply both sides by $c$ for the first part and see what you can deduce.

Comment: how does having c = c(ax + by) help?

Comment: $a$ divides the RHS by assumption and hence divides the LHS